# Slidetoggle Not working properly on child element of the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

On clicking `.cart-contents-toggle` the `#cartplus-dropdown` div should slide down and at the same time slide up without clicking on it a second time. Here is the URL where this is implemented: [Website Link](https://englishbook.com.pk/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#cartplus-dropdown').hide();
  jQuery('.cart-contents-toggle').on("click", function() {
    jQuery('#cartplus-dropdown').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Your actual page is using `jQuery('this').next().next().slideToggle();` That is the problem. Use the code shown in the question and it works fine

Comment: i have added the same , But this is not working right it will slidedown and up automatically on one click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the updated code below and let me know if you have any issue or query.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('.cart-contents-toggle').on("click", function() {
   jQuery('#cartplus-dropdown').toggle();
    jQuery('#cartplus-dropdown').slideToggle();

  });
});
```

Hope this may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this and working now

```
jQuery('.c-btn').mouseenter(function(e) {
  jQuery('.cartplus-dropdown').slideDown();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
jQuery('.c-btn').mouseleave(function(e) {
  jQuery('.cartplus-dropdown').slideUp();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```